# Save file to pickel with nested loop indeces as filen names

Tags: python, matlab

Im converting my code from matlab to python. In matlab to save my variables i usually do this

```
for i =1:4
    for j=1:3
      save(['data_',int2str(i),'_' int2str(j)'.mat'],'var1', 'var2' )
    end
end
```

so in the end i have files like: data_1_1, data_1_2 etc

How can i modify the code below to have a similar naming convention

```
import pickle
Tests = 5
data = {}
for i in range(Tests):
   for j in range(4)
    data['r'] = 5
    data['m'] = 500
    data['n'] = 500
    data['X'] = np.random.rand(data['m'],data['n'])
    data['Y'] = np.random.rand(data['m'],data['n'])
    with open('data{}.pickle'.format(i), 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(data, f)
```

I would like to save my pickled as say data_1_2 etc

Help! im new to python. thanks!

Comment: Use `open('data_{}_{}.pickle'.format(i+1, j+1), 'wb')`

Comment: could you tell me why we do i+1, or j+1 since its a for loop shouldnt it do the incrementation automatically?

Comment: Python uses 0 (zero) based indexing whereas matlab is 1 based. So in Python: `list(range(4)) == [0, 1, 2, 3]`. This page has a lot more info on transitioning from matlab to  Python and NumPy: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html

Comment: thanks a lot. if you have time could u look at this short question?
https://stackoverflow.com/q/58040984/10647736?sem=2