# How can I remove some entries in a matrix. I am converting from matlab to python

Tags: python, matlab

Here is a matlab code i would like to convert

```
m=100;
n=100      
idx_MV = randperm(m*n);
Q = ones(n, m);
Q(idx_MV(1:round(MV*m*n))) = 0;
```

can i get a python equivalent of this piece of code? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you could try it :

```
import numpy as np
q = np.ones((2, 1))
q[your_index_function(args)] = 0
```

and `your_index_function(args)` must return a same shape array as `q` with boolean values according to your conditions (like `idx_MV` behavior?)

Comment: I have no idea. im new to all this. please kindly see my edited question, maybe u will understand the it better. thank you.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. What is `MV` ?

Comment: MV is just a value. say MV=0.3

Comment: Ok I guess you can use `numpy.random.permutation(m*n)` in place of `randperm(m*n)`,

Comment: what about the last part Q(idx_MV(1:round(MV*m*n))) = 0; it gets the positions in the matrix Q and set it to 0 using the values from (idx_MV(1:round(MV*m*n). How can i write this in python.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Thanks @Ludovic

```
m=100
n=100
MV=0.4
idx = np.random.permutation(m*n)
idx2 = idx[1:round(MV*m*n)]
Q.reshape(-1, 1)[idx2] = 0
```